# LINQ order by a number sequence

Tags: c#, linq, list, sql-order-by

I have a list of products with their category ID, like:

```
ID      CategoryID     Product Name
1       1              Product 1
2       1              Product 2
3       7              Product 3
4       8              Product 4
5       9              Product 5
6       10             Product 6
```

I want to take this list and order by a list of categoryID, like: 1, 8, 9 and the rest, so I get:

```
ID     CategoryID     Product Name
1      1              Product 1
2      1              Product 2
4      8              Product 4
5      9              Product 5
3      7              Product 3
6      10             Product 6
```

There is any way to this with linq?
Thanks

Comment: By using `orderby`? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: You first need to define your order in "math". 1, 8, 9, 7, 10 is not a regular order. You can add an index like: {1,1},{8,2},{9,3},{7,4},{10,5} and sort by the index.

Comment: This would really be funny if the OP mistyped the result he's looking for and it _is_ as simple as a straight numeric `orderBy`...still great and interesting solutions, but funny still.

Answer (score 5):

If your category IDs are in a list, you can order like that:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 8, 9, 7, 10, ... };

var productsOrdered = from p in products
    let index = list.IndexOf(p.CategoryID)
    order by (index < 0 ? int.MaxValue : index) // in case it is not in the list
    select p;
```

This query will work only with Linq to Objects, so you need to bring all data unordered from your database.

Comment: This would work, but it would be nasty if `list` was very large.

Comment: Depends though. Below a certain number, yours comes in ahead - no time wasted setting up the dictionary and the constant factors of iterating a list are lower than in looking up a dictionary, so `IndexOf` is faster than `TryGetValue` for small collections. I think it's worth nothing the value of both approaches.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the 1,8,9 is in a list, we'll call `orderList`, then while we can keep looking for the position in the list each time, we'll be faster to create a dictionary to look it up quickly.

```
var orderDict = orderList.Select((o, index) => new {ID = o, Order=index}).ToDictionary(oi => oi.ID, oi => oi.Order);
int orderHolder;
var orderedProducts = products.OrderBy(p => orderDict.TryGetValue(p.CategoryID, out orderHolder) ? orderHolder : int.MaxValue);
```

We don't strictly need to set-up `orderDict` first, but it makes the logic simpler than scanning through the list every time, and also quicker: O(n + m) rather than O(nm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):

```
var catIDs = new[] { 1, 8, 9 };
var ordered = products
    .OrderByDescending(p => catIDs.Contains(p.CategoryID))
    .ThenBy(p => p.CategoryID);
```

Edit: Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/O462C

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from p in productsList
            orderby p.CategoryID descending
            select new {ID = p.ID, CID = p.CategoryID, PName = p.ProductName};
```

`query` now contains the products list inordered sequence. You can enumerate through it like:

```
foreach(Product prod in query)
   Console.WriteLine(prod.CID);
```

Edit: Misunderstood the answer. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know everything that you want to sort at the top of the list, try this:

```
var products = new List<Product>();

products.Add(new Product { ID = 1, CategoryID = 1, ProductName = "1" });
products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, CategoryID = 1, ProductName = "2" });
products.Add(new Product { ID = 3, CategoryID = 7, ProductName = "3" });
products.Add(new Product { ID = 4, CategoryID = 8, ProductName = "4" });
products.Add(new Product { ID = 5, CategoryID = 9, ProductName = "5" });
products.Add(new Product { ID = 6, CategoryID = 10, ProductName = "6" });

products
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CategoryID == 1 || p.CategoryID == 8 || p.CategoryID == 9)
    .ThenBy(p => p.CategoryID);
```

Produces this (from LinqPad):

```
ID CategoryID ProductName 
1  1          1 
2  1          2 
4  8          4 
5  9          5 
3  7          3 
6  10         6
```

Comment: Put the second last category in `products` in first, and it comes out first in the results, which is incorrect.